# Android Front Facing Camera by default

Tags: android, cordova, camera

Alright I have an application that is going to go on a specific android device that has a front facing camera.

I need to use the front facing camera by default. The min API I have set is 9. I have tried looking everywhere and since I am such a newbie to JAVA, I am lost.

Here is my code snippet if you could please elaborate on how the code works I will appreciate it greatly!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;

import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Camera permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

and Camera's are for `APIs >=9`, so you're okay.
This is the front Camera intent, use it in your code

```
int CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
```

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: Ok, I followed what you said but it still used the back camera. I am using an Asus EEEpad Android version 4.0.3. Also, I added the:
 int CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;

after the code above. I added the permissions in the manifest.xml, am I missing something else?