# Phonegap/Cordova - Front-facing camera by default in Android

Tags: android, cordova

I tried the solution at [Android Front Facing Camera by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079555/android-front-facing-camera-by-default), but still it is using the back-facing camera. Can someone please provide the full code to get the front-facing camera?

Comment: There are no errors, it is just giving back the back facing camera. Also verified logcat, but couldn't find any userful information

Comment: open camera with id 1 when you starting camera first time. Nothing more.if you are simply calling existing camera through phonegap using intent,it is not possible.try custom camera.

Comment: Thanks, @Amrendra, i'm using a function capturePhoto to use the camera  function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL});
    }
please show me where to add the id i used the last option as cameraId: 1 after DATA_URL, but it didn't worked

Comment: sry frnd. phonegap will not help you in current form.you have to go 4 custom camera.

Comment: @Amrendra: But according to latest phonegap 2.8.0 version, there is an option to select the camera facing. Please refer here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Camera.Direction = {
    BACK : 0,           // Use the back-facing camera
    FRONT : 1           // Use the front-facing camera
};

But i couldn't implement it, please let me know where to include this option to select camera front facing

Answer (score 1):

cameraDirection property is used to set the camera direction(front/back). You have to add it in the options like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, cameraDirection:1, destinationType:        destinationType.DATA_URL}); }
```

"1" is used for front-facing camera and "2" is used for back-facing camera.

Comment: This isn't working at my end for android 6.0.1 only. It works for all earlier versions but open back camera as default camera for android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This code will flip the camera on older devices and ios devices, but will not change the default facing on newer android versions.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { 
    quality: 50, 
    cameraDirection:1, 
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL}); 
}
```